# finding a vector valued function for the intersection of two shapes

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametric

I have a problem for my cal 3 class to find a vector valued function for the intersection of these two equations.

$4x^2+4y^2+z^2=16$
  and
 $x=z^2$

so i know that the first equation is a ellipsoid and the second is a folded sheet or cylinder.  I also believe that I need to use the parametric equation for an ellipsoid to come up with my final vector valued equation. I know i can get theta by putting the $4y^2$ over $4x^2$ and taking the arc sign, but I'm  having trouble perameterising these and then uniting them with a common t.  An explanation for how to setup and solve this problem would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the information provided,$5z^2 +4y^2 = 16$, which is an ellipse in the $y-z$ plane.  You can now use parameterize this curve using trig functions.

Answer:

> $$\dfrac{5z^2}{16} + \dfrac{y^2}{4} = 1 $$ $\implies$
>  $$ \mathbf{r}(t) = \left<y(t),z(t)\right> = \left< 2\cos(t), \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{5}} \sin(t) \right>$$

Comment: So subbing the x out of the original equation will yield the equation of the intersection? also would I be parameterizing using the y = a sin theta cos phi and z = c sin theta?

Comment: Yes.  See my hidden answer after you have tried.

Comment: Demetri, I got the z value but I'm lost on how you came up with the 2cos(t) rather then 2sin^2(t)

Comment: @James I need the term $\frac{y^2}{4}$ to be equal to $ \cos^2(t)$.  Try equating those two and solving for y.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but i thought that the equation for y was y= b sin(theta) sin (phi) (where theta and phi are t in this case)  do i just have the parametric equation for y copied down incorrectly?

Comment: never mind, I understand what your doing, because after dividing by 16 we have an equation that fits the form of Sin^2 + cos^2 = 1 you are setting the first portion equal to sin^2 and the second portion equal to cos^2 and solving for x and y which can be put into a vector valued function.  Thank you for all the help, wish my professor had explained the why of the thing instead of just working examples.